# Android animation not working on ProgressBar

Tags: android, android-animation

I am trying to use Animations in my android project however I try it doesnt work this is the line I am using to animate the progress bar.

```
ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar)convertView.findViewById(R.id.pb_loading);          
progressBar.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getSherlockActivity().getApplicationContext(),android.R.anim.fade_out));
```

This is my XML.

```
  <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/pb_loading"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:layout_width="64dp"
        android:indeterminate="true"
        android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/spinner"
        android:indeterminateDuration="2000"
        android:indeterminateOnly="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
```